# how to replace a error message (2753) with an pop up window (WIX)

Tags: wix, wix3

I want to know how to replace a message error for a pop up window on Wix.

I've a Installer that have two different Features and when I don't select any option an error message appears:
"The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package.  This may indicate a problem with this package.  The error code is 2753."

```
<Feature Id="Complete" Title="App"
         Display="expand" Level="1" AllowAdvertise='no' InstallDefault='local'>

  <Feature Id="App1" Title="App1.exe" Level="1" AllowAdvertise='no' InstallDefault='local'>
    <Condition Level="0">INSTALL_GUEST_FEATURES = 0</Condition>

    <ComponentRef Id="App1Executable" />
  </Feature>

  <Feature Id="App2" Title="App2.exe" Level="1" AllowAdvertise='no' InstallDefault='local'>
    <Condition Level="0">INSTALL_HOST_FEATURES = 0</Condition>

    <ComponentRef Id="App2Executable" />

  </Feature>
</Feature>

<UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
```

Can I replace this message for a pop up window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom dialog box and pass the error message into it. See my code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="InvalidDBConnDlg" Width="260" Height="120" Title="[ProductName]">
                <Control Id="OK" Type="PushButton" X="102" Y="90" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="OK">
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Text" Type="Text" X="48" Y="22" Width="194" Height="60" Text="[DBCONNERR]" />
                <Control Id="Icon" Type="Icon" X="15" Y="15" Width="24" Height="24" ToolTip="Information icon" FixedSize="yes" IconSize="32" Text="WixUI_Ico_Info" />
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

From your custom action you need to set the value of DBCONNERR and call this dialog box if certain  condition are not met